# Synchronization fails in TimerTask

Tags: java, synchronization

I am developing an ODL app and have scheduled a task (`MonitorLinksTask`) from my main function in order to monitor delay in all links of a topology. ***I want to send one packet per link, and after it has been received by the controller, send the next one for the next link.*** Code in `main` is :

```
Timer time = new Timer();
MonitorLinksTask monitorLinksTask = new MonitorLinksTask();
time.schedule(monitorLinksTask, 0, 5000);
```

Class `MonitorLinksTask` is :

```
public class MonitorLinksTask extends TimerTask{

    static boolean flag = false;

    public void run() {

        for (DomainLink link : linkList) {
            sendPacket();
            while (flag == false){
                 //waits until it gets notified that the sent packet has been received
            }
            System.out.println("Sending next packet.");
            System.out.println("----------");
            flag = false;
        }

    }
}
```

where :

```
private void sendPacket(){
    Packet packet;
    PacketProcessingService packetProcessingService = ... ;
    // .... fill the packet ....
    System.out.println("Packet transmitted at time " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    packetProcessingService.transmitPacket(packet);
}
```

So **up to here**, every 5 seconds the task runs and calls the function to send a packet per link, in order to compute the single-trip delay of each link in the graph.

I have created a Listener so that each time the controller receives a packet, it notifies the `MonitorLinksTask` that it received the packet, and then `MonitorLinksTask` can send the next one.

```
public void onPacketReceived(PacketReceived packetReceived) {

    System.out.println("Packet received at time " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    MonitorLinksTask.flag = true;

}
```

However, my program works correct for the first two executions of `MonitorLinksTask` and the third one stops. Example output for case with two links :

```
Packet transmitted at time 1549333576093
Packet received at time 1549333576096
Sending next packet.
Packet transmitted at time 1549333576111
Packet received at time 1549333576115
Sending next packet.
----------
Packet transmitted at time 1549333576122
Packet received at time 1549333576124
Sending next packet.
Packet transmitted at time 1549333576128
Packet received at time 1549333576129
Sending next packet.
----------
Packet transmitted at time 1549333576136
Packet received at time 1549333576140
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming all of this happens in the same single JVM: 1) Add `Thread.currentThread().getName()` to your logs, so its clear from logs if execution is multi-threaded or single-threaded; 2) If former, try adding `volatile` modifier to `flag`.

Comment: @VictorSorokin Thanks a lot!! The problem seems solved now. You can make your comment an answer so that I accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all of this happens in the same single JVM:

1. Add `Thread.currentThread().getName()` to your logs, so its clear from logs if execution is multi-threaded or single-threaded;
2. If former, try adding `volatile` modifier to `flag`.

Since above helped to resolve your issue, it's clear that it was caused by lack of visibility updates between threads (`TimerTask` thread and your app thread(s)). Let me suggest [Oracle Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) to further your knowledge of Java multi-threading. Your specific issue is mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html).